# Email address validation in php (other than filter_var)

Tags: php, regex, validation, email, filtering

Hey it's my second question regarding email address filtering but I am really paranoid and I don't like the fact people can still "bypass" the default email address validation in php.

An example:

```
$i = "email@[1.1.1.1]";
if (!filter_var($i, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
$msg = "Invalid email address"; 
} else { echo "valid email!"; }
```

This echos "valid email!", if you were wondering.

Is there a solution that prevents it? I want people to be able to register only using conventional email addresses (name@domain.ltd). A complex regex? a library? I can't seem to find a solution.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

That IS a valid email-address. So... I don't see the problem. But you can do something like this (granted, this utilizes all of the filter-methods in one function, so you can shorten it a bit):

```
function filtervariable($string,$type,$method) {
    //function for sanitizing variables using PHPs built-in filter methods
    $validEmail = false;

    if ($method == 'sanitize') {
        $filtermethod = 'FILTER_SANITIZE_';
    } elseif ($method == 'validate') {
        $filtermethod = 'FILTER_VALIDATE_';
    } else {
        return;
    }
    switch ($type) {
        case 'email':
        case 'string':
        case 'number_int':
        case 'int':
        case 'special_chars':
        case 'url':
        $filtertype = $filtermethod.strtoupper($type);
        break;
    }

    if ($filtertype == 'FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL' && !empty($string)) {
        list($local,$domain) = explode('@',$string);

        $localLength = strlen($local);
        $domainLength = strlen($domain);

        $checkLocal = explode('.',$domain);

        if (($localLength > 0 && $localLength < 65) && ($domainLength > 3 && $domainLength < 256) && (checkdnsrr($domain,'MX') || checkdnsrr($domain,'A') || ($checkLocal[1] == 'loc' || $checkLocal[1] == 'dev' || $checkLocal[1] == 'srv'))) { // check for "loc, dev, srv" added to cater for specific problems with local setups
            $validEmail = true;
        } else {
            $validEmail = false;
        }
    }
    if (($filtertype == 'FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL' && $validEmail) || $filtertype != 'FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL') {
        return filter_var($string, constant($filtertype));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know it's a valid email address according to the standards, but nobody uses an IP address instead of a domain, and there are many other examples of valid yet strange emails passing the filter. I'll take a look at the function you included, thanks!

Comment: @Hector Especially at [`checkdnsrr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php#117880) have a look.

Comment: "nobody" being a bit categorical. Having email for an IP is perfectly valid, albeit not that common - it is, however, a way to have a less obvious email - set up an email-server on an IP, and as long as that IP isn't specifically registered, tracking it becomes a bit less easy, for instance (without spoofing anything).

Comment: @Hector, what's wrong with accepting "valid yet strange emails"? If they're valid, they're valid. Restricting emails beyond the scope of the standard is irresponsible. It's no better than saying, "My users can only have Gmail addresses. Anybody using any other domain is out of luck."